# Random search grid not displaying scoring metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I want to do a grid search of some few hyperparameters through a XGBClassifier of a binary class, but whenever i run it the score value (`roc_auc`) is not being display. I read in other question that this can be related to some error in model training but i am not sure which one is in this case.

My model training data `X_train` is a `np.array` of `(X, 19)`

[image]

and my `y_train` is a `numpy.ndarray` of shape `(X, )` which looks like this

[image]

And then i create my model params and model in this way

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

# A parameter grid for XGBoost
params = {
        'min_child_weight': [1, 5, 10],
        'gamma': [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5],
        }
xgb = XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='logloss')

folds = 3
param_comb = 5

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle = True, random_state = 1001)

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, 
                                   param_distributions=params,
                                   n_iter=param_comb, 
                                   scoring='roc_auc',
                                   n_jobs=4, 
                                   cv=skf.split(X_train, y_train), 
                                   verbose=3, 
                                   random_state=1001)

random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Whenever i hit code from above i am seeing this display which doesnt contain the scoring

```
[CV 3/3] END ..................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=5; total time= 3.6min
[CV 1/3] END ..................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=1; total time= 3.7min
[CV 3/3] END .................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=10; total time= 3.5min
[CV 1/3] END ....................gamma=2, min_child_weight=5; total time= 3.6min
[CV 2/3] END ..................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=1; total time= 3.5min
[CV 2/3] END .................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=10; total time= 3.4min
[CV 2/3] END ..................gamma=1.5, min_child_weight=5; total time= 2.5min
[CV 2/3] END ..................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=5; total time= 3.5min
[CV 2/3] END ....................gamma=2, min_child_weight=5; total time= 3.4min
[CV 3/3] END ..................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=1; total time= 3.6min
[CV 1/3] END ..................gamma=1.5, min_child_weight=5; total time= 2.5min
[CV 1/3] END ..................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=5; total time= 3.6min
[CV 3/3] END ....................gamma=2, min_child_weight=5; total time= 3.5min
[CV 1/3] END .................gamma=0.5, min_child_weight=10; total time= 3.4min
[CV 3/3] END ..................gamma=1.5, min_child_weight=5; total time= 2.5min
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of the evaluations for each fold are stored in the `RandomizedSearchCV` instance after fitting. Access them using the `cv_results_` attribute:

```
# Access CV validation scores.
print(random_search.cv_results_)
```

Note that you can also access the best estimator with:

```
best_estimator = random_search.best_estimator_
```

More in the documentation of [`RandomizedSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html).